# What should I do with one answer copy/paste in different questions?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers

While I was browsing the [new answers to old questions tool](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) <sup><sub>(> 10k rep only)</sub></sup>, I noticed this user, [Chancho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1920044/chancho), was posting the very same answer in every question related to Facebook FQL:

- [Paging in Facebook FQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192338/paging-in-facebook-fql/24071028#24071028)
- [Paging with FQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392810/paging-with-fql/24087114#24087114)
- [FQL: Limit and Offset variance return unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410324/fql-limit-and-offset-variance-return-unexpected-results/24087121#24087121)
- [Facebook FQL stream limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062085/facebook-fql-stream-limit/24087128#24087128)
- [FQL equivalent to Graph API pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058438/fql-equivalent-to-graph-api-pagination/24087138#24087138)

What should I do in this case (and any future similar)? Burn my flag votes to flag every post with a comment that says it should be close as a duplicate? Check if the answer is relevant to each question even though I am not an expert about this topic? Ask moderators to look at this user?

Comment: Flag it and let someone who is an expert on the topic have a look to see if it is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to do anything. The system automatically raises a flag on every single post when a user posts *exact* duplicates of their answers across multiple questions. So we already have flags on them all.

If you have some pertinent information that moderators should know when handling these, feel free to flag one of them in the chain. Otherwise, consider it handled.

If you know anything about the subject, consider analyzing the questions to see if they're duplicates. That's always helpful, too.

Comment: Does auto-flagging work for posts that started out different but were made the same following a later edit?