# What to do with identical duplicates?

Tags: discussion

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717685/how-to-remove-x-powered-by-in-expressjs), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867199/cant-get-rid-of-header-x-powered-byexpress) questions.

Working in my own business, I had a need, Googling a bit and found these two duplicate questions. Questions asked 3/2 years. Both are valid and have the same response accepted and a second identical response with a link between them. I mean the second answer of the second question has a link to the second answer to the first question.

The latest, has a comment "possible duplicate" voted 4 times (I gave +1) 
I put a flag accordingly. but now I have more questions than answers.

Here there is no new knowledge. It is a fact.

Does the duplicate question should be removed?

Is legitime the reputation obtained (+510)? (i mean for the user who copied and pasted and put a link)

Should join these questions into one?

Is this just a case of something that happens often or a isolated issue?

Comment: 3 answer which already should have been close votes and many upvotes which could have been close votes too, nothing to do there anymore closing as duplicate does not seem too popular in all :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both questions are of about the same quality, but one of them have significantly higher view count - I'd keep that as main and make other duplicate.

There generally no need to touch answers in question marked as duplicate.

If one of the questions have brilliant answer (not this case) you may try to merge that answer to main duplicate. Consider "use wiki and point back" suggestion from [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)

If there is copy-pasted answer (to any question in general) - consider checking if user tends to do so and flag as "other" if you found it to be a pattern for particular user (with details). Or you can leave comment... See also [What should I do with one answer copy/paste in different questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258660/what-should-i-do-with-one-answer-copy-paste-in-different-questions)

Comment: Thanks Alexei, really helps me understand how things work around here.